# Caching parent classes in mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, mongodb, mongoid

This is my data structure.

```
Foo  
  has_many: bar

Bar  
  belongs_to: Foo
```

I am trying to write a caching method for Bar that will pull out only "featured" entries.

```
def self.get_featured  
  Rails.cache.fetch("featured", :expires_in => 1.day) do  
    self.where(:featured=>true)   
  end  
end
```

That works. However, the views which display this data also call for information such as
`featured.foo.title` which is not cached as part of the .get_featured method.

Every time I call something like that, the db gets hit again, which happens >40 times per page, thus causing the db to implode a little.

Question, how can I cache filtered Bar AND Foo information for all the filtered records of this Bar?

Answer (score 2):

You can use mongoid [includes](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#includes) to eager load the data by specifying the relation names. But currently it is limited to 1 level deep. So i believe it will eager load the foo along with featured, but not sure about the bar. You can try it yourself

```
def self.get_featured  
  Rails.cache.fetch("featured", :expires_in => 1.day) do  
    self.includes(:foo,:bar).where(:featured=>true)   
  end  
end
```

In order to make it work, the Mongoid identity map must be enabled in the mongoid.yml like this

```
identity_map_enabled: true
```

Comment: This seems to have worked in itself, but doesn't work for the way I've got things set up. This methods was supposed to pull data into a '@featured' variable and then render a partial with :collection => '@featured'.
however, I get a can't modify frozen object error, when I try that.
I wonder if that's because I have view caching on those objects. Will try different approach.